# Windows Phone browser resize images

Tags: windows-phone-8, browser

Hi I have a Windows Phone app and been trying to have the browser window resize the images on the page to fit the browser window.

I notice the emulator window does this but when I deploy to the phone I get large images. Been searching about for an answer for this. Maybe this is something I've overlooked and simple?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting `Viewport` meta tags as required.To do so just add meta tag code at start of your `html` string, as:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

you can also use `minimum-scale` property.

Comment: Hi I'm writing the app which views webpages via a browser EG Facebook etc. Have no control over the HTML, the apps webbrowser resises on emulator but not when I deploy on the phone!?

Comment: are you using emulator that is same as your device? resolution etc may differ.